# Why doesn't .Net use an object's actual type when referenced as a base-class, and what can I do about it?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

[MRE on .NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NzEuwY)

```
using System;

class Base {}
class SubClass1 : Base{}
class SubClass2 : Base{}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test(new Base());
        Test(new SubClass1());
        Test(new SubClass2());
        
        var o = new Base(); Test(o);
        o = new SubClass1(); Test(o);
        o = new SubClass2(); Test(o);
    }
    
    static void Test(Base o) => Console.WriteLine($"Test Base on {o.GetType()}");
    static void Test(SubClass1 o) => Console.WriteLine($"Test SubClass1 on {o.GetType()}");
    static void Test(SubClass2 o) => Console.WriteLine($"Test SubClass2 on {o.GetType()}");
}
```

**Test Base on Base

Test SubClass1 on SubClass1

Test SubClass2 on SubClass2

Test Base on Base

Test Base on SubClass1

Test Base on SubClass2**

Why does .Net not match the 'best' method in the second set of calls, and use the referenced type rather than the actual object type? Just "because it does" or because this would lead to many other problems in the language?

Other than having to explicitly check the type (maybe using a [switch pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching)) is there a workaround?

Comment: The overload to call is determined at compile-time. At compile-time, `o` has the type `Base`. Since you're calling `Test` and passing an argument which has a compile-time type of `Base`, the compiler chooses the `Test(Base o)` overload

Comment: seems like that could be an answer @canton7

Comment: ... if you want to defer the overload resolution until runtime, use `dynamic`: `dynamic o = new Base() ...`. That of course comes with the associated runtime costs and loss of compile-time type checking

Comment: This is such basic C# knowledge that it's sure to be a dup

Comment: Not sure anything about `dynamic` would be considered that basic :) it's not widely used at all in my experience (perhaps for a good reason)

Comment: thanks for the dupe suggestion. The answer there is actually quite neat IMO